# Django / Apache: How to limit my server to receive requests for a specific amount of time

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django / Apache application which runs heavy and time consuming algorithms on server side. I want to limit my server in order to receive 2 requests per 3 hours from all users.
I took a look in this excellent package: https://github.com/jsocol/django-ratelimit but I cannot find the way to block requests from all IPs for a specific amount of time.

I feel that the answer is in front of my eyes but I cannot find it.
Any solution ?